# How do I open the JavaScript console in different browsers?

Tags: web-development, javascript, browsers, debug

Web browsers provide a JavaScript console as part of their developer tools. This console is useful for the following reasons:

- Errors and warnings that occur on a web page are logged into the console.
- JavaScript commands for interacting with a web page can be executed in the console.

What are the keyboard shortcuts for opening the console in different browsers?

Comment: I went and made a tinyurl that links here, so if you need to instruct an audience of varied browser folks to open their javascript console... http://tinyurl.com/jscons

Comment: Refer this url ,this url have screenshot :so you will easily get this :https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/#:~:text=To%20open%20the%20developer%20console,(on%20Windows%2FLinux).

Answer (score 83, accepted):

## Chrome

Opening the “Console” panel of Chrome’s **DevTools**:

- Windows and Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
- Mac OS: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

*Note: In addition to the “Console” panel, there also exists a smaller slide-up console which can be toggled via <kbd>Esc</kbd> while any of the other panels is active.*

[Full documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/shortcuts)

---

## Firefox

Opening the “Console” panel in Firefox’s **Developer Tools**:

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
- Mac OS: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

*Note: In addition to the “Console” panel, there also exists a smaller slide-up console which can be toggled via <kbd>Esc</kbd> while any of the other panels is active.*

[Full documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts)

---

## Internet Explorer

Opening the “Console” panel in Internet Explorer’s **F12 Developer Tools**:

- <kbd>F12</kbd>, then click on the “Console” tab

*Note: In addition to the “Console” panel, there also exists a smaller slide-up console which can be toggled via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> while any of the other panels is active.*

[Full documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn322041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

## Safari

*Note: In order to view the console in Safari, you have to enable the “Show Develop menu in menu bar” setting in the “Advanced” pane of Safari’s preferences ([screenshot](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html)).*

Opening the “Console” panel in Safari’s **Web Inspector**:

- <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

*Note: In addition to the “Console” panel, there also exists a smaller slide-up console which can be toggled via <kbd>Esc</kbd> while any of the other panels is active.*

[Full documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/KeyboardShortcuts/KeyboardShortcuts.html)

---

## Opera

- Windows and Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>
- Mac : <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

[Full documentation](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/)

Comment: In Firefox, it can opened in a separate window (and be global - not just for the current tab) by menu *Tools* → *Web Developer* → *Browser Console*.

Comment: **F12** works in many browsers.

Comment: The Opera documentation link is no longer valid, the shortcut is correct though.

Answer (score 11):

To *indirectly* reach the Console in Opera (checked on v9.6) the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> while on Safari 5 (on Windows) it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

I wish all the browser makers could get together to [standardize the keyboard shortcuts](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2008/09/keyboard-shortcuts-common-to-firefox-ie.html).

Update: It appears that the REPL tab under the Scripts tab in Opera Dragonfly in Opera 11 is similar to the Console option that was available in previous Opera versions.

I did not found much documentation on REPL after a cursory search, [except for this article](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/opera-dragonfly-for-opera-11-goes-final-and-a-new-experiment) which has an indirect reference.

I tried this command in REPL with the Google home page open & it executed fine i.e. it hid the Google logo -
document.getElementById('logo').style.visibility = 'hidden';

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + I will open the dev tools in Opera. But where is the JavaScript console? Where can I input JavaScript code and execute it?

Comment: CTRL + ALT + I does nothing in my Safari 5 on Windows 7. Can you confirm that it works?

Comment: That could be because you do not have the Develop menu option enabled. To activate this option, go to Edit > Preferences & in the Advanced tab enable the "Show Develop menu in menu bar" checkbox option.

Comment: That was my problem. Stupid Apple disabling developer features by default. `:)` Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is it. I overlooked that REPL tab at the bottom LOL