# Are the links in JavaScript considered as Toxic Backlinks?

Tags: seo, google, javascript, backlinks, seo-audit

I have the similar question as asked at [Does Google count external Javascript or CSS files as backlinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107725/does-google-count-external-javascript-or-css-files-as-backlinks)

Actually, I have suddenly found an increase in a number of backlinks and decrease in my SEO rankings.

I checked all these new sites from where I gained the links, but cannot find my website URL when I used View Source option (Ctrl + U)

So is it possible that my website's URL is included in the Javascript and Google is counting them as backlinks and they are classified in toxic backlinks? However, I haven't received any notification in webmasters.

Is there any way to check the URLs in the Javascript?

Comment: As indicated in the linked question, backlinks are _links_, not URLs. You can simply request the JavaScript file you want to look at in your browser to view its source code, or use its [Developer Tools](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers). You can't really control which site links to yours, but you can _disavow_ them - see Google's help doc on how to [disavow backlinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en).

Comment: I address the notion of a toxic link in this answer. First things first, there is no such thing as a toxic link, however, there are link patterns that could be of concern. I explain it here. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83825/what-is-a-toxic-link/83835#83835